# Set a font icon like font awesome or genericons as a custom menu_icon in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, font-awesome

I'm  now adding a custom post type in wordpress.

```
function custom_post_type() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                => 'Custom Type',
        'singular_name'       => 'Custom Type',
        'menu_name'           => 'Custom Type',
        // ....
    );
    $args = array(
        // ...
        // The below matters!
        'menu_icon' => get_template_directory_uri().'/images/my-icon.png',
    );
    register_post_type( 'custom_type', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_type', 0 );
```

#### My trouble is:

I want to set the `menu_icon` as a font-icon, like font-awesome or genericons.

How can I do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this is not a fully solution for my question, but it solved my problem:

Wordpress after 3.8 use a subset of dashicons as its menu icons.

If we want to use the icon sets of dashicons, just wrote the icon name.

e.g.

```
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-welcome-view-site',
```

**See:**

https://developer.wordpress.org/resource/dashicons/#format-image

And I wrote a post for an example:

http://www.huangwenchao.com.cn/2015/03/wordpress-dashicon.html